# Get pod with given IP in Kubernetes go api

Tags: go, kubernetes

I'm using the kubernetes go api. I have the IP of a pod, and I want to find the v1.pod object (or just name and namespace) of the pod that has that IP. How can I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you need to use a FieldSelector. The field in this case is `status.podIP`.

```golang
import (
    [...]
    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    [...]
)

[...]

pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("").List(context.Background(), metav1.ListOptions{FieldSelector: "status.podIP=" + address})
```

Where `clientset` is a `*kubernetes.Clientset` and `address` is the string IP of the pod